# How i place right this bootstrap package to my Laravel project?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I want these toggle bootstrap buttons from this website [toggle buttons](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) and i dont know the right way of doing this....

**So far i did..**

I just copy the **css** files on my **css** folder the **JS** files to my **JS** folder and there is another doc file that has inside 5 more files i do what with them and then i do update composer ? Or what is next ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

You Can keep it under this path:

**/public/assets/css/yourstylesheet.css**

And you don't have to required update composer.

Comment: you can make saperate folder or you can merge it with JS or CSS folder.

Comment: why there is a 3rd folder inside sorry im confused...there is another script.js file and stylesheet.css file what i do with them ? Expect the whole folder that are for js and css files....